# Servers DNS name

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

if I setup a Windows Server 2008R2 instance on one of our servers and name it:

```
DC01.corp.domainname.com
```

Is the 'normal' procedure to point a dedicated public IP address to it and then add a CNAME to the domain name?

So if a user were to want access remotely to the router then the full DNS name would resolve?

Sorry if this isn't making much sense, I don't fully understand the usual conventions of naming servers and their domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A name is a dynamic thing, and servers especially can have more than one. Take for instance a .NET web-app server such as used for Outlook Web Access. Depending on the roles it has, it can have any of the following names:

- The AD name of the server itself (Exch2010-CA1.AD.example.com)
- The internal DNS name of the OWA server used for convenience (webmail.ad.example.com)
- The external DNS name of the OWA server used for outside logins (webmail.example.com)
- The external DNS name in the MX record for example.com (smtp1.example.com)

DNS names are not one-to-one with servers. Servers in shared-hosting farms can have thousands of DNS names pointing to the same server.

As for the active directory DNS-domain, in my above example, the DNS domain 'ad.example.com' may be completely unresolvable from the outside. Intentionally so, even. It prevents those tasty SRV records being used as a hacking hit-list.

In your case, DC01 should probably have a private address and not bother with a public one. Remote access to that would be done via public IP, probably proxied by way of a NAT gateway with a port-forward, and the DNS used there would be whatever you want it to be.